# Group magento admin grid column headings

Tags: grid

I have a requirement to group/categorize column headings of a grid layout which will result in 2-level column heading.

For example,let we have 5 columns in a grid named as : First Name,Last Name,Email,Company,Designation .....Now,I want to group/categorize them in "Personal Info" and "Professional Info" by adding these two top level headings.

So,Under "Personal Info" heading I will have 3 columns with headings - First Name,Last Name,Email and under "Professional Info" heading I will have Company and Designation headings....Can I achieve this ??If yes,then can anybody help me to find out how can I do this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported by default in magento.
There is the code that renders the headers in a grid (code from `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml`)

```
<?php if ($this->getHeadersVisibility()): ?>
    <tr class="headings">
    <?php foreach ($this->getColumns() as $_column): ?>
        <th<?php echo $_column->getHeaderHtmlProperty() ?>><span class="nobr"><?php echo $_column->getHeaderHtml() ?></span></th>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but here is my idea. Unfortunately I don't have a full functioning solution for it.

Use a different template for your custom grid.
You can clone the file I mentioned above and modify the clone.
You can tell your grid block to use the clone template by adding this

```
$this->setTemplate('path/to/clone/grid.phtml');
```

in the constructor of your grid block after calling `parent::__construct`.

Then you should change the code I mentioned to include an other `<tr>` element that will hold your column group labels.
This is where my idea stops. I don't know yet how you can manipulate the columns to make them use groups.

Comment: This is more than enough for me ,It will make my work.Thanks